# Transform integral limits

Tags: definite-integrals

Assume that the following relation holds
\begin{align}
p\int^1_{\frac{p}{a}} f(\theta)d\theta = \int^p_a f(\theta)d\theta
\end{align}
where $p$ is some scalar and $a\in[0,1)$. Is there some general rule which confirms the example at hand? Actually I need to know how a factor in front or within the integral can be connected to the interval boundaries.

**Edit**

Sorry, apparently it shall read 
\begin{align}
p\int^1_{\frac{a}{p}} f(\theta)d\theta = \int^p_a f(\theta)d\theta
\end{align}
where the lower bound is reversed.

Comment: one thing: $a \not = 0$.

Comment: I think you meant $a / p$ in the lower bounds on the left integral. That would make more sense

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_{a} ^p f(\theta) d \theta = 
\int_{a/p} ^{p/p} f \left( p \theta \right) p d \theta =
p \int_{a/p} ^{1} f \left( p \theta \right) d \theta
$$
is the correct equality.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvotes? That would be helpful in order for me to revise my answer.

Comment: This cannot possibly be correct, as the values of the functions on different intervals are independent of each other and can yield completely different integrals.

Comment: I believe the correct calculation should be: $$
\int_{a} ^p f(\theta) d \theta = 
\int_{a/p} ^1 f \left( p \theta' \right) p d \theta' =
p \int_{a/p} ^1 f \left( p \theta \right) d \theta 
$$

Comment: Thanks @LorenoHeer and Dominik for pointing out my sloppy errors - looks like I was trying to write it up and should have taken more time to actually check what I was writing before I submitted.

Comment: Cheers @LorenoHeer. Is this result standard? Do you mind pointing to references since I'm from econ. Say $f$ is given by $f(\theta)=1-\theta$. What's exactly $f(p\theta)$?

Comment: @clueless, $f(p \theta) = 1 - p \theta$. This result just comes from a "u" - substitution, or change of variables, in the integrand.

Comment: @clueless If $f(\theta) = 1 - \theta$ then $f(p \theta) = 1- p \theta$.

Comment: I reckon that I can go in the reverse direction by $p\int^1_{a/p} f(\theta)d\theta=\int^p_a f(\theta/p)d\theta$ ?!

Comment: @clueless exactly.